# Writing an Emulator and need to be able to reference methods/functions in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am writing an Emulator in Ruby for a relatively simple 6502 processor.

My question is, is there a way to define a hash or array with details of the assembly instruction, followed by the number of operands it takes, and finally, the method/function that implements it?

Then somewhere in the code, the hash or array can be evaluated based on the instruction read, and the appropriate method/function implemented for it can be launched?

I am open to ideas...

Currently, I have such a structure, but am having difficulties implementing it:

```
@inst.push [ 0x48, :implied, 1, PHA]
@inst.push [ 0xA2, :immediate, 2, LDX ]
@inst.push [ 0xA9, :immediate, 2, LDA ]
@inst.push [ 0xAD, :absolute, 3, LDA ]
@inst.push [ 0xA6, :zeropage, 2, LDX ]
@inst.push [ 0xB6, :zeropagey, 2, LDX ]
@inst.push [ 0xAE, :absolute, 2, LDX ]
@inst.push [ 0xBE, :absolutey, 2, LDX ]
@inst.push [ 0x8A, :implied, 1, TXA ]
```

Lambdas, Procs? Can anything like that work for what I am aiming to achieve here?

I really don't want a big "Case/When" for each instruction followed by the statements in one huge, ugly and relatively unfriendly place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your instructions are implemented as methods you don't need lambdas. Specify methods using symbols with their names, get actual methods using `Class#method` and call it using `Method#call`. What I mean is

```
method = Object.method :puts
method.call "Oh, it seems to work!"
```

In your case it would be

```
implementation = Instructions.method instruction_name
# Store it in a hash in which instruction names are keys or any other
# appropriate data structure. Once you encounter this instruction...
implementation.call
```

Comment: The trick was using method(methodname).call. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `send` to call any method on an object

```
>> a = [1,2,8]
=> [1, 2, 8]
>> a.send(:size)
=> 3
>> a.send(:pop)
=> 8
>> a
=> [1, 2]
>> a.send(:push,42)
=> [1, 2, 42]
```

so just store the name of the methods which implement your instruction as symbols in the array and then send the symbol to the interpreter to call the associated method.